# Azure cache programatically configuration fail to verify

Tags: caching, azure

Not sure if Azure cache has recently changed, however the access keys seem to have a slightly different format.

I followed the instructions from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618003.aspx

I setup the cache factory programatically and it works a treat.
However, after I added another cache to our system, the new cache doesn't work.
The error I get is:

```
ErrorCode<ERRCA0029>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Authorization token passed by user Invalid.
```

I'm accessing the cache in the same way as before, only difference is the different host and the different key.

The first cache I setup (that is working), has auth token that is 232 characters long.
the new cache has a key that is only 204.
Not sure if this is relevant but I'll give as much info as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618003.aspx are for working with the same cache but with distincts endpoints. For example adding https access to your current cache.

If you wish to work with 2 Azure Cache, just build 2 distinct objects with 2 independent implementations.