# Azure cache programatic configuration results in ErrorCode ERRCA0029 SubStatus ES0001 Authorization token passed by user Invalid

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-caching, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying Proof of Concepts based on code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618003. This cache is accesible if I use app.config settings. When I switched the application to use programatic configuration, I consistently get this error. I have already tried [Azure cache programatically configuration fail to verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633783/azure-cache-programatically-configuration-fail-to-verify) and many other solutions to no avail.

Here's my code snippet.

{code}

```
        String                              acsKey = "AcsKey removed intentionaly";
        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration       cacheFactoryConfiguration;
        DataCacheSecurity                   dataCacheSecurity;
        DataCacheServerEndpoint[]           serverEndpoints = new DataCacheServerEndpoint[1];
        SecureString                        secureAcsKey = new SecureString();

        serverEndpoints[0] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("EndPont removed intentionaly", 22243);

        //
        // Create SecureString from string
        //
        foreach (char keyChar in acsKey)
        {
           secureAcsKey.AppendChar(keyChar);
        }
        secureAcsKey.MakeReadOnly();
        dataCacheSecurity  = new DataCacheSecurity(secureAcsKey);

        //
        // Initialize Factory Configuration
        //

        cacheFactoryConfiguration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration(); // This line throws exception. Note that the key is yet to be assigned to SecurityProperties as per documentation.
        cacheFactoryConfiguration.Servers = serverEndpoints;
        cacheFactoryConfiguration.SecurityProperties = dataCacheSecurity;

        _cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(cacheFactoryConfiguration);
        _cache = _cacheFactory.GetDefaultCache();
```

{code}

Comment: I just figured this out. I had used NuGet's installation instructions (cause the documentation says so). This adds a configuration entry that I did not realize was there. It had the templatized version of file and was causing problems. Once I removed it, the code started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing all the params at creation and not post creation?

```
    var configFactory = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration
                            {
                                Servers =
                                    new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>
                                        {new DataCacheServerEndpoint(cacheServer, cachePort)},
                                SecurityProperties =
                                    new DataCacheSecurity(Encryption.CreateSecureString(cacheAuthorization),
                                                          true)
                            };
```

Comment: I found the issue to be something different. I did not find Encryption.CreateSecureString anywhere. The snippet of code does work as well (once I fixed the app.config issue).